# mysql - count from different table supplemented with another count from subresult

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, as defined below. (folders and adressbook entries, connections in the connection table as its a 1:many table. An addressbook can be in multiple folders)

I'm trying to get a list of folders, which is easy.
I added a COUNT(total) of how many entries are in the folder, which was easy as well.

But I also need to add another COUNT of how many of those COUNT(total) have an addressbook_lastchecked of 0

So more or less I need a count of total names in that folder and then another count of how many of that total are unchecked...

```
**addressbook**
    addressbook_id
    addressbook_lastchecked
    addressbook_name

**folders**
    folder_id
    folder_name

**folders_connections**
    connection_id
    folder_id
    addressbook_id
```

My effort so far.. I need to sub select don't i?

```
SELECT f . * , c.lastchecked, COUNT( c.lastchecked ) AS entries
FROM folders AS f
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT fc.folder_id, a.lastchecked
FROM folder_connections AS fc
LEFT JOIN addressbook AS a
USING ( addressbook_id ) 
WHERE a.lastchecked =0
) AS c
USING ( folder_id )
```

My additional effort is (which is incorrect, because it has duplicates.)

```
SELECT f.*, COUNT(c.connection_id) AS entries, COUNT(csub.connection_id) AS unchecked  
FROM folders AS f 
LEFT JOIN folder_connections AS c USING(folder_id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT fc.*, ab.lastchecked FROM folder_connections AS fc 
     LEFT JOIN addressbook AS ab USING(addressbook_id) WHERE ab.lastchecked=0) AS csub USING(folder_id)
GROUP BY c.folder_id ORDER BY folder_name Asc LIMIT 0, 15
```

SOLVED by mixing 2 of the things.

```
SELECT f.folder_id, f.folder_name, SUM( 
CASE c.lastchecked
WHEN 0 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END ) AS unchecked, COUNT( c.lastchecked ) AS entries
FROM folders AS f
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT fc.folder_id, a.lastchecked
FROM folder_connections AS fc
INNER JOIN addressbook AS a
USING ( addressbook_id )
)c
USING ( folder_id ) 
GROUP BY f.folder_id, f.folder_name
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: If your question is `do you need to sub select?` then yes you need to sub select the queries to get the result.

Comment: No, my question is more... so how do i subselect it? where in the query..

Comment: Instead of COUNT you can SUM(case ab.lastchecked when 0 then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: Yes thank you that worked, which eliminated the double LEFT JOIN as well. Only needed to compbine the folder_connections tbale with the addressbook table, then add another select SUM(... to it...worked like a charm.

Comment: somehow it was only showing the ones that had a conneciton and not showing 0 for ones without connection, so combined this with the below answer and that worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to the extent I understand below is the solution:

First take the enteries where `addressbook_lastchecked is 0`

```
SELECT fc.folder_id, a.lastchecked
FROM folder_connections AS fc
Inner JOIN addressbook AS a // Inner join is a best option as you get all folders
USING ( addressbook_id ) 
WHERE a.lastchecked =0
```

// Now you have all folders where lastchecked is `0`

Now take count of folders and count of last checked by combining both queries.

```
SELECT f . folder_id,f.folder_name
 , count(c.lastchecked) checkedcount, COUNT( c.lastchecked ) AS entries
FROM folders AS f left join (    SELECT fc.folder_id, a.lastchecked
    FROM folder_connections AS fc
    Inner JOIN addressbook AS a // Inner join is a best option as you get all folders
    USING ( addressbook_id ) 
    WHERE a.lastchecked =0) c
USING ( folder_id ) 
group by f . folder_id,f.folder_name
```

now you have folder ID and corresponding count and checked count.

Let me know if this not you are looking for.

Comment: this looks alright, but somehow the totals are incorrect... though mixing it with the comment of Serpiton... the final one is  (see in my post)

Comment: Ok I am missing 'case' I am glad you solved also thanks for correcting me... :)

Comment: Yeah I would like to have given Serpiton credit as well. ANyway thanks for your help.. and serpiton